# .deb for SystemD created from debian:packageBin for Play 2.4.2 App Does Not Have Permisison to Create Log

Tags: playframework-2.0, debian, sbt, sbt-native-packager

How can a SystemD install script created by `sbt debian:packageBin` set up permissions for the webapp to write to the PID `/var/run` or a subdirectory?

Only root has permission to create a `pid` file in `/var/run` or to create a directory like `/var/run/myWebApp/` that holds a `pid` file. The `debian:packageBin` task causes the webapp to run as a special `user:group` created from the name of the webapp. If a directory is created like `/var/run/myWebApp`, the `myWebApp` group needs write permission, but I don't see any way to make this happen automatically. Am I missing something?

Here are some of my config files:

`dist/conf/application.ini`:

```
-Dpidfile.path=/var/run/webapp2/webapp2.pid
```

`conf/application.conf`:

```
# This seems redundant ... should it be removed?
pidfile.path = /var/run/webapp2/pid
pidfile.path = ${?pidfile.path}
```

`debian.sbt`:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.ServerLoader.{Systemd, SystemV, Upstart}
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager.autoImport._

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala, DebianPlugin)

enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
enablePlugins(JDebPackaging)
enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging)

serverLoading in Debian := Systemd

maintainer in Linux      := "Mike Slinn <mslinn@mslinn.com>"
packageSummary in Linux  := "myWebApp blah blah"
packageDescription       := "myWebApp blah blah"
daemonUser in Linux      := normalizedName.value        // user which will execute the application, resolves to "myWebApp"
daemonGroup in Linux     := (daemonUser in Linux).value // group which will execute the application, resolves to "myWebApp"
```

**Update:**

[Play manages its own pid.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Production#Play-PID-Configuration). I was not able to get `${{app_name}}` to expand, so I hardcoded `myWebApp` instead.

The [sbt-native-packager docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/java_server/my-first-project.html#default-mappings) say that the pid should be placed in `/var/run/myWebApp` and the logs in `/var/log/myWebApp`.

`/var/run` has permission 777 is symlinked to `/run` with permission 775; both are owned by `root:root`. Thus the only way for a non-root process can write to `/var/run` is for a directory to be created under `/var/run` with the appropriate permissions. For example, `postgres:postgres` has permission to write to `/var/run/postgres`:

```
$ ls -adlF /var/run/postgresql
drwxrwsr-x 3 postgres postgres 120 Aug 28 01:17 /var/run/postgresql/
```

This is how the Play docs show placing the pid in `/var/run` should work, however this does not work for me.

Comment: It should be done automatically, did you try your set up?

Comment: Yes I tried, and it did not work as described

Comment: -Dpidfile.path=/var/run/webapp2/pid and your appname is myWebApp? Could you post an output of ls -l /var/run/myWebApp?

Comment: For play application you could use same directory for pid but different name eg play.pid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, placed in `debian.sbt`:

```
linuxPackageMappings += packageTemplateMapping(s"/var/run/${name.value}/")() withUser name.value withGroup name.value
```

There was no need for the extra entries in `conf/application.conf`.

Comment: Play application create pid file and tries to do create it in run directory which is /usr/share/appName and isn't writable. So, for play app you need additional settings for pid file.

Comment: Perhaps you did not notice that I wanted to create the PID file in /var/run/myWebApp/, like a standard Linux service. That should have been abundantly clear. Your suggestion does not do that. My solution is tested and works. I also don't appreciate the downvote.

Comment: pid file will be created in /var/run/appName by start up system. And play application itself will try to create another one in work directory which isn't writable for daemonUser. Also this dir is added to linuxPackageMappings by JavaServerAppPackaging. I'll remove downvote if in bother you, no prob (:

Comment: And may be I have an obsolete data about play framework since I didn't use latest version.

Comment: Behavior has changed. I am using current version of Play and all plugins. Your information is out of date. It is difficult to figure out this stuff, because the docs do not agree with each other, are out of date, and the behavior changes every release. Note also that /var/run/appName is only writable by root; see my detailed explanation above.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/2bfc9596df24afc6bd13b0f52a54f6f6e31e9a0d/src/main/resources/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/archetypes/java_server/systemloader/systemd/start-template

Comment: Problem is solved, thank you. I have provided the answer. Tomorrow I will accept my own answer since SO does not allow me to accept it yet.